# Is it possible to alter an Array object's length?

Tags: arrays, ruby

How does one alter `self` in an `Array` to be a totally new array? How do I fill in the commented portion below?

```
class Array
  def change_self
    #make this array be `[5,5,5]`
  end
end
```

I understand this: [Why can't I change the value of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834446) and know I can't just assign `self` to a new object. When I do:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

`arr` contains a reference to an `Array` object. I can add a method to `Array` class that alters an array, something like:

```
 self[0] = 100
```

but is it possible to change the length of the array referenced by `arr`?
How are these values stored in the `Array` object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking three very different questions in your title and in your text:

> Is it possible to alter an `Array` object's length using an `Array` method?

Yes, there are 20 methods which can (potentially) change the length of an `Array`:

- [`<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) increases the length by 1
- [`[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) can alter the length arbitrarily, depending on arguments
- [`clear`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-clear) sets the length to 0
- [`compact!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-compact-21) can decrease the length, depending on contents
- [`concat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-concat) can increase the length, depending on arguments
- [`delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-delete) can decrease the length, depending on arguments and contents
- [`delete_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) can decrease the length, depending on arguments
- [`delete_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) / [`reject!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) can decrease the length, depending on arguments and contents
- [`fill`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-fill) can increase the length, depending on arguments
- [`insert`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-insert) increases the length
- [`keep_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-keep_if) / [`select!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-select-21) can decrease the length, depending on arguments and contents
- [`pop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-pop) decreases the length
- [`push`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-push) increases the length
- [`replace`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-replace) can alter the length arbitrarily, depending on arguments and contents (it simply replaces the `Array` completely with a different `Array`)
- [`shift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-shift) decreases the length
- [`slice!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-slice-21) decreases the length
- [`uniq!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21) can decrease the length, depending on contents
- [`unshift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-unshift) increases the length

> When monkey patching the Array class, how does one alter "self" to be a totally new array? How do I fill in the commented portion below?
>
> ```
> class Array
>  def change_self
>    #make this array be [5,5,5] no matter what
>  end
> end
> ```

```
class Array
  def change_self
    replace([5, 5, 5])
  end
end
```

> How are these values actually stored in the `Array` object?

We don't know. The Ruby Language Specification does not prescribe any particular storage mechanism or implementation strategy. Implementors are free to implement `Array`s any way they like, as long as they obey the contracts of the `Array` methods.

As an example, here's the `Array` implementation in [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/), which I find fairly readable (at least more so than YARV):

- [`vm/builtin/array.cpp`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/vm/builtin/array.cpp): certain core methods and data structures
- [`kernel/bootstrap/array.rb`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/bootstrap/array.rb): a minimal implementation for bootstrapping the Rubinius kernel
- [`kernel/common/array.rb`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/array.rb): the bulk of the implementation

For comparison, here is [Topaz](http://topazruby.com/)'s implementation:

- [`lib-topaz/array.rb`](https://github.com/topazproject/topaz/blob/master/lib-topaz/array.rb)

And [JRuby](http://jruby.org/):

- [`core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyArray.java`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyArray.java)

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr.replace([5,5,5])
```

I wouldn't monkey-patch a new method into Array; especially since it already exists. [Array#replace](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-replace)

Comment: You could also use [Array#[\]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D): `arr = [1,2,3]; id = arr.object_id; arr[0..-1] = [4,5]; arr #=> [4, 5]; arr.object_id == id #=> true`.

Answer (score 2):

As `Array` are mutables, you can alter it's contents:

```
class Array
  def change_self
    self.clear
    self.concat [5, 5, 5]
  end
end
```

You modify the array so it becomes empty, and then add all the elements from the target array. They still are two different objects (ie, `myAry.object_id` would differ from `[5, 5, 5].object_id`), but now they are equivalent arrays.

Moreover, the array *still is the same* that before - just it's content changed:

```
myAry = [1, 2, 3]
otherRef = myAry
previousId = myAry.object_id
previousHash = myAry.hash
myAry.change_self
puts "myAry is now #{myAry}"
puts "Hash changed from #{previousHash} to #{myAry.hash}"
puts "ID #{previousId} remained as #{myAry.object_id}, as it's still the same instance"
puts "otherRef points to the same instance - it shows the changes, too: #{otherRef}"
```

Anyway, I really don't know why one would want to do this - are you solving the right problem, or just kidding with the language?