# Why can't I change the value of self on Int32

Tags: crystal-lang

If I try to implement an additional method, which doesn't change the value of `self`, on `Int32` it works:

```
struct Int32
    def double
        self * 2
    end
end

x = Int32.new 2
p! x.double # => 4
```

However, as soon as I try to change `self` the compiler gives me an error, why? Is there a way to do this or is it completely impossible in Crystal?

```
struct Int32
    def six
        self = 6 # This fails
    end
end
```

I've also tried this on `String` and `Char`, I get the same compiler error: `Error: can't change the value of self`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beta Ziliani's answer is good and looks at the bigger picture.

For this particular example, the answer is actually very simple: primitive types in Crystal are immutable.
So it's impossible to change the value of a primitive type's instance. Mutating methods always have to return a *new* value. That value can then be assigned to the same variable again.

A workaround would be to wrap the primitive in a struct. Or as an unsafe alternative, you can pass a pointer to a variable with a primitive value to a method. Then the method can assign a value to that pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: what is `self`? The answer depends on the class:

- If it's a `Value` (`Int32`, `Char`), then its value (what you want to change) is copied when passed around: there isn't one place in memory where you can go and perform the change.
- If it's a `Reference` (`String` and most user defined classes), then `self` is a pointer to an object. That means that if you were able to change `self`, you're modifying the *pointer*, and not its content.

As a final note, [this applies to Ruby too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834446/why-cant-i-change-the-value-of-self).

Comment: Switch seems to allow assigning to `self` at least in some cases: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Methods.html#ID240

Apart from that, I can't remember any language where this is possible. Maybe Dom has some insights where this idea comes from?